# Show loading indicator with PDFObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdfobject

I need to show some sort of indicator while the PDF is loading. I'm displaying PDFs that can take 40 seconds or longer to be generated and embedded.

I'm aware that I can check to see if the PDFObject embedded successfully (by using [this](http://pdfobject.com/examples/conditional-js.html) example). However, this doesn't give an indication when the file finished downloading.

I'm also aware that I can style it. However, that doesn't work either, since it retains that style after the PDF loaded. Also, while I can style the border, positioning, height, etc of the object, I can't get attributes like `cursor` to work:

```
#pdf object {
  border: 5px solid red;       // does work, but still shows up after the PDF loads
  cursor: progress !important; // doesn't work
}
```

Is there any way I can see when the file successfully downloaded?

Comment: Consider using `PDF.JS` instead. It has a built in loading progress-bar. Though browser support is not as good.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, PDF readers (including the native ones and 3rd party like Adobe Reader) do not provide load percentage details. PDFObject has no way of knowing how large the file is, or how much longer it will take to load the file.

Comment: I was thinking of just adding a spinner that's hidden when the pdf loads. I was hoping that one of these libraries would have some sort of callback when the file finishes loading, but I guess not.

Comment: You can only do a callback if there's a way to verify that the file has finished loading. This feature was not added to PDF readers. It's available in Flash, which is why you see so many SWF load indicators, but the PDF reader industry did not follow suit.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is still a old post but if you still looking for a solution. you can try to make a `<div>` position relative and then the spinner inside the div absolute with `z-index` of 99 and then the pdfobject also with a position relative and `z-index` 99 that way the pdfobject will go on top of the spinner than is looks like the pdf is loaded.

```css
div.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative; }

#spinner {
position: absolute;
z-index: 99; }

#pdf-container {
width: 100%; /* optional */
margin: 0 auto; /* optional */
border-bottom: 1px solid #666; /* optional */
position: absolute;
z-index: 99; }
```